# Arguments to PyUnit not parsed correctly

Tags: eclipse, pydev, python-unittest

When we try to run a PyUnit test in Eclipse as a Python unit-test, it fails. This is because the arguments sent to PyUnit come in the following order: file-to-test --port portno. We have discovered that there is an environment variable called POSIXLY_CORRECT that, if set, makes PyUnit expect the arguments to come in a certain order, options first.

We have looked everywhere in Eclipse to try and find where these arguments are set, but are unable to find them. So as a workaround we change the run configuration to use an environment without the POSIXLY_CORRECT set. But this is very awkward.

Does anyone know how to solve this so that we do not need to modify the run configurations to be able to run our tests?

Comment: We use Eclipse 3.7.1 and PyDev 2.4.0.